# Accessing struc members NASM Assembly

Tags: nasm

Coming from Object Oriented languages such as Python and Java, why is this code not working as I would like it to?

I want to access the cat struc variable cat_name and send it to STDOUT to print in my terminal.

**catstruct.asm:**

```
SECTION .bss
    struc cat
        cat_name: resb 8
    endstruc

SECTION .data
catStruc:
    istruc  cat
        at cat_name, db "Garfield" 
    iend


SECTION .text
GLOBAL  _start

_start:
    mov     edx, 8
    mov     ecx, cat_name
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
```

No errors when the code assembles, however, it does not print anything when I run it. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cat_name just contains 0, the offset of the cat name from the start of the struct, you need

```
mov     ecx, catStruct+cat_name
```

quote from the manual

> For example, to define a structure called mytype containing a
> longword, a word, a byte and a string of bytes, you might code
>
> ```
> struc   mytype 
>
>   mt_long:      resd    1 
>   mt_word:      resw    1 
>   mt_byte:      resb    1 
>   mt_str:       resb    32 
>
> endstruc
> ```
>
> The above code defines six symbols: mt_long as 0 (the offset from the
> beginning of a mytype structure to the longword field), mt_word as 4,
> mt_byte as 6, mt_str as 7, mytype_size as 39, and mytype itself as
> zero.